# android image button - mouse over

Tags: android

I have an Imagebutton and I want when mouse over to change the image.

```
            <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnClubs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/clubs"  >
            </ImageButton>

final ImageButton clubsButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnClubs);
```

I noticed that I can not put method mouseleave or mouseenter.
Thanks

Comment: Mouse? For an android device?

Comment: what do you mean by mouse hover ? where do you get a mouse in android device ??..wait for  Android device to have a mouse ...

Comment: so I consider mouse - "the finger over ", now i don t have any device yet , i test just with emultaor , on this is "mouse". Sorry for my mistake

Comment: @Raluca Gurau why mouse, why not elephant then?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Selector` for the background of your `ImageButton` and i think you mean to say focus change not mouseover